# Cannot resolve host with CNAME but can directly?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I don't understand why this CNAME is not working:

```
$ curl test8-kounta.test.kounta.com
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'test8-kounta.test.kounta.com'

$ curl test8.kounta.com
# Success

$ curl 54.187.189.133
# Success

$ nslookup test8-kounta.test.kounta.com

Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
test8-kounta.test.kounta.com    canonical name = test8.kounta.com.
Name:   test8.kounta.com
Address: 54.187.189.133
Name:   test8.kounta.com
Address: 54.69.18.31
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Works for me. Clear your local DNS cache and try again?

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks @Rup